# Load Testing couchbase server - Unable to capture calls triggered from couchbase lite to sync_gateway

Tags: websocket, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

Our mobile app uses couchbase lite (version 2.7) and it replicates the data to couchbase server through sync_gateway. Now we want to capture the calls being triggered from couchbaseLite to the sync_gateway. we need to capture these calls because we want to simulate these calls in our load testing tool and load test the sync_gateway directly from our load test tool.

we tried using charles proxy to capture these requests, but however we are not able to capture the replication requests. Only request i could capture is _blipsync call (and that too in websocket format).

I understand that couchbaseLite 2.7 talks to sync gateway in websocket layer. But is there a way i can capture the requests triggered from couchbase lite to the sync_gateway for push/pull replications?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [cblite CLI tool](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-mobile-tools/blob/master/README.cblite.md) for simulating a Couchbase Lite client.  You can launch a number of instances of the client, preferably on a beefy cloud instance that you can scale up to handle a large number of clients. The tool also includes a mini HTTP listener that allows you to interact with the tool via a REST API.

Another Java based client that you can use for simulating a client is available [here](https://github.com/Infosys/CouchbaseLiteTester) and [a blog](https://www.infosysblogs.com/open-source/2020/08/New%20open%20source%20CBLite%20Tester%20streamlines%20data%20synchronization%20with%20Couchbase%20Sync%20Gateway.html) goes along with it.